# Excel - Windows 7 Taskbar Progress

Tags: winapi, vba, excel, taskbar

Running Excel 2010, I can assuredly always be running these sheets on this version, as it will only be accessed locally exclusively on my work's terminal computers.

I run a number of import process and large folder filtering/printing batch functions via excel. I am wanting to utilize the Windows 7 taskbar progress bar visual while my functions process, giving an idea of how  far they are along. Considered going with other visual effects for showing the progress, but this(if possible) seems the most obvious and professional style to do so.

I've been looking thoroughly into trying to make this work, to no avail. My understanding thus far is that I need to impliment the ITaskbarList3 interface, commonly found within the Windows API. From the code I have found showing how to make it work, once implimented the rest seems fairly easy and self-explanatory.

I am completely restricted to using Excel as the basis for the code, no installation permission on the work computers. I can install at home to get any files necessary, and then transfer them. Happy to use any extensive or really backwards ways to get to the end, as the ends justify whatever means it takes.

Comment: No, you don't implement `ITaskbarList3`. That's implemented by the system. You need to consume it. You'll need to call `CoCreateInstance` to create an instance of `ITaskbarList3`. You'll also need access to the main Excel form's window handle. Sounds like you are restricted to VBA for this. Good luck.

Comment: Actually, I'm far from convinced that it's even possible to consume `ITaskbarList3` from VBA. I have a feeling you can only consume automation interfaces. In which case it's game over.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Alright, so currently looking like it just isn't a possibility within the confines of Excel then? Sad day.

Answer (score 4):

It would be much easier to use the Excel Status Bar:

Application.StatusBar = "Show progress to user...";

---

For the Windows & Taskbar progress bar you need to download the 
[Windows 7 taskbar: Developer Resources](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Windows7Taskbar/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2246).

You'll need to open the sample solution, right click on the Windows7.DesktopIntegration project > properties > Build > Tick Register for COM.

By checking the "Register for COM interop" option in the IDE during development, the IDE will call regasm on the target assembly together with the /codebase option.

This will cause regasm.exe to add the following registry entry for a COM-visible class exported from your assembly :

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}\InprocServer32\CodeBase=

*This will enable the CLR to locate your assembly by following the path to your assembly.
Without the codebase path, the CLR will have to locate your assembly (and its dependencies) using the standard search algorithm.*

Next Build the solution > goto the bin folder the Windows7.DesktopIntegration project and copy the Windows7.DesktopIntegration.DLL and Windows7.DesktopIntegration.TLB to the System32 folder or better yet Register to the GAC.

*One related technique that helps the CLR to locate required assemblies is to copy all assemblies (and their dependencies) to the same folder as the client application itself. However, the client application in your case will be Excel. This means that you must copy the assemblies into the same folder as the Excel application (not a good idea).*

Once you are able to instantiate the Windows7.DesktopIntegration DLL, you should be able to call the `Windows7Taskbar.SetProgressValue` method, eg VBA code:

```
Set Windows7Taskbar = CreateObject("Windows7.DesktopIntegration")

Windows7Taskbar.SetProgressState(form.Handle, Windows7Taskbar.ThumbnailProgressState.Normal)

Windows7Taskbar.SetProgressValue(form.Handle, progress, maximum)
```

Comment: OP is restricted to VBA. Registering COM components is not going to work.